# How to return to the directory from where I ran the batch script file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My folder structure is like some thing below,
C:\WORK\Project\
Inside the above path there are multiple sub folders,
1. Src
2. bat
3. output
etc.
All my batch script file are present in C:\WORK\Project\bat\
So I will be going to the same directory and run my batch script file.
But as my source code and all present in side C:\WORK\Project\Src path so in my batch script file the path mentioned as C:\WORK\Project\

Problem :-
After finishing my batch command as the path mentioned C:\WORK\Project\ so it is going to the same folder in command prompt. But I want to be in C:\WORK\Project\bat from where I started my command.please let me know hoe to achieve this.

As there are many folders inside C:\WORK\Project\ which I need to take into consideration so I have to set my path in batch script file as C:\WORK\Project.

Answer (score 0):

from the prompt, try

```
pushd /?
```

and its friend,

```
popd /?
```

Comment: And even I want to do some changes in script file so that user no need to give any command from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to include in the batch file, before any directory change

```
setlocal
```

This will make changes to the environment local to the current batch file. When the batch file finishes or when `endlocal` command is used, any change to the environment, including changes to the current active directory, will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . It is working for me now.